# Atypical way to find angle between unit vectors: $\theta = 2 \sin^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{2}\left\|\hat{A}-\hat{B}\right\|\right)$

Tags: linear-algebra, trigonometry, vectors

At my work, I have come across code with the following way of calculating the angle between two vectors.

> $$\theta = 2 \sin^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{2}\left\|\hat{A}-\hat{B} \right\|\right)$$

(Note the physics convention: $\hat{v}$ indicates the normalization of $v$; ie, $\hat{v}:=v/\|v\|$).

I've spent some time, but I can't think of how this was derived using typical methodologies (law of sines, law of cosines, dot product, cross product). It is pretty different. So my questions is,

> How could this have been derived?

Comment: @DavidK Thank you. I have addressed that.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This works when $A$ and $B$ are unit vectors.

You have 
$$
\|A-B\|^2=(A-B)\cdot(A-B)=\|A\|^2+\|B\|^2-2\,A\cdot B=2-2\cos\theta=4\sin^2\tfrac\theta2.
$$
Solving,
$$
\theta=2\arcsin\tfrac{\|A-B\|}2.
$$

Comment: A general comment: note the hats on the vectors, which often indicates normalization.

Comment: Good to know! I haven't seen that in the last 30 years of doing math.

Comment: It's fairly common in physics, I think. Some people denote the standard unit vectors in $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ with $i,j,k,$ and some of those people put hats on them, to emphasize that they are unit vectors.

Comment: I have been using the hats on $i,j,k$ for many years, but I never saw the notation being used for other vectors.

Comment: Thank you! I was thinking there was going to be a square/root step in there somewhere

Comment: @WillR It's indeed common in physics. We often go one step further too, and write stuff like $\vec{v}=v\hat{v}$. Makes for fairly compact notation.